# Why is IceCube more sensitive to Northern hemisphere events?

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrinos

I am reading about neutrino detectors, especially about IceCube Neutrino detector and while going through some papers I found the statement "IceCube is more sensitive to point sources in the northern hemisphere than in the southern hemisphere." from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube_Neutrino_Observatory) and [this site](https://aasnova.org/2017/08/08/where-are-the-icecube-neutrinos-coming-from/%22this%20site%22) which I am not able to understand.

What might be the reason?

Comment: More noise coming from the southern sky :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand it. Could you explain a bit more or direct me towards some article?

Comment: Yes, the noise is due to atmospheric muons from the southern sky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a lot more mass/material between the South pole and the northern hemisphere (namely the earth) than between the South pole and the southern hemisphere, noise-inducing particles such as muons (as mentioned in the comments) are absorbed/scattered before they reach your detector.

This follows from the fact that the Earth has a much higher density than the atmosphere.